# How to flip a ByteBuffer relative to the mark?

Tags: java, nio

Is there a built-in way, or alternatively, what is the cleanest way, to flip a java NIO ByteBuffer relative to the mark?

That is, `flip()` sets `limit := position` and then `position := 0`.  I would like a `flipToMark()` routine that sets `limit := position` and then `position := mark`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flipping clears the mark, so unfortunately `buffer.flip().reset()` won't work.

How about `buffer.limit(buffer.position()).reset()`?

Answer (score 0):

In many cases it may be easier to create a view buffer starting at `mark` (e.g. using `slice()`), instead of actually setting the `mark`. In this case you can use the regular `flip()` method.